# How to post a string to web API controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to web API. Using Visual Studio Community 2015. Very simple testing code.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );
```

View:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/ClassingAlgorithm/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { userWeightings: JSON.stringify('hello') }
        });
```

Controller:

```
public class ClassingAlgorithmController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ClassingResult PostWeightings([FromBody]string userWeightings)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the controller method, "userWeightings" is always null. Why?

Comment: I have indeed looked through many posts incl. those on Stackoverflow. They all said the above shall work, but it just doesn't. I spent 8 hours trying all options and possibilities, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: can you change it to `data: { userWeightings: 'hello' }` and try. I really think `Json.Stringify` is the issue. just check in chrome network tab... what exactly is posted to server

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax request as below.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'api/ClassingAlgorithm/',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:  JSON.stringify('hello') 
    });
```

Comment: I put following line in the method:

Comment: string strReq = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadT‌​oEnd();

Comment: strReq is: userWeightings=%22Hello%22

Answer (score 0):

I just worked out the solution:

Working code has the following in the $.ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(userWeightings),
```

The not-working code has

```
data: { userWeightings: JSON.stringify(userWeightings) },
```

But I don't understand why.